# Why does the output of the NSString work but unable to use the actual variable?

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, base64

My app gets data from an RESTful service, decodes and unzips the data. However, it doesn't appear to be fully working.

decodedString remains empty when using notWorkingInput - if I Copy&Paste the NSLog of notWorkingInput into the NSString input, the code works perfectly..

Why does notWorkingInput fail but input doesn't - They contain exactly the same data.

CODE:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
  ^(NSData *receivedData,
    NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
    NSError * _Nullable error) {


      //this is not working
      NSString *notWorkingInput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSLog(@"Input %@", notWorkingInput);

      //THIS IS THE EXPECTED OUTPUT FROM THE ABOVE NSLog - this works but notWOrkingInput doesn't
      //NSString *input = @"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";


      NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:notWorkingInput options:0];


      NSData *unzippedData = [decodedData gunzippedData];
      NSString *decodesdString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unzippedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      NSLog(@"DECODED STRING   %@", decodesdString);





  }] resume];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a raw string (which is not a part of JSON, xml, whatever..) from data, you might easily end up with a little bit different output - resulting string will contain some escape sequences, like `\n` or `\t`, which `NSLog` won't print for an apparent reason. These characters definitely prevent strict data structures (like Base64) from being made.

To get it round just add the `IgnoreUnkownCharacters` options in your Base64 data constructor:

```
[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodeString:notWorkingInput options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
```